# Dual space of t.v.s. endowed with weak topology

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

When thinking about dual spaces and weak topologies, I came up with the following thought:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological vector space and let $X^{\prime}$ be its (topological) dual space. Now, this dual space gives rise to a weak topology on $X$. Let us denote by $(X_w, \tau_w)$ the original space $X$ endowed with the weak topology. Now, I consider the dual space of this space, i.e. $X_w^{\prime}$. Then $X_w^{\prime} \subset X^{\prime}$. This dual space gives rise to an even weaker topology on $X$, which I denote by $(X_{ww},\tau_{ww})$ and so on and so forth. Iterating this, the topology becomes coarser and coarser. Can one say anything about the "limit topology"? Has this question been investigated at all? I haven't found anything about it in my search.

Thanks for your replies!

Best,
Luke

Comment: If $X$ is a vector space and $X'$ is a subspace of the space of all linear functionals  on $X$, then $X$ with the weak topology induced by $X'$ has dual $X'$ with respect to this topology. This is Theorem 2.4.11 in Megginson's *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory*. Perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: You're right. So in my example above, actually $X_w^{\prime}=X^{\prime}$. I wasn't aware of that result. Thank you!